# Is WS Websocket able to send or receive json object in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, websocket

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_NSInlineData)'

```
let data = /* type of data */
let dic : NSDictionary = ["ID" : "UserName", "Data" : data]
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: [])
self!.socket.write(data: jsonData!)
```

Comment: Th error is pretty clear: JSON does not support `Data`, only string or number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible because socket writes string or buffer can't accept an object. I can send it when I convert data to base64 and convert jsonData to String.
But I want to send it as Data.

```
let data = /* type of data */
let dataAsString = data!.base64EncodedString()
let dic : NSDictionary = ["ID" : "UserName", "Data" : dataAsString]
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
self!.socket.write(string: jsonString!)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. Please delete this "answer" and update your question as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Create a string from your data and you can send that.

```
func jsonToString(json: AnyObject) -> String{
    do {
        let data1 =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let convertedString = String(data: data1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return convertedString!
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
        return ""
    }
}
```

You can use it:

```
let messageString = jsonToString(json: jsonData as AnyObject)
   socket.write(string: messageString)
```